# Clique number of the Hajos Construction of a Graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Prove that $\omega(G)-1 \leq \omega(H(G,v_1,v_2)) \leq \omega(G) $.

The $H(G,v1,v2)$ indicates the Hajos Construction of a graph. I can prove this for $K_n$ but I have no idea how to generalize for all graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that G has $K_n$ as a subgraph (it obviously has at least $K_2$), we know that its clique number is $\omega(G)$. Removing $v_1 v_2$ will either result in the removal of an edge from the complete subgraph or removal of an edge not from the complete subgraph. In the first case, our largest subgraph becomes $K_{n-1}$ (i.e clique number = $\omega(G)-1$) and in the second case, the clique number is unchanged.

Combine those two cases and you easily get that $\omega(G)-1 \leq \omega(H(G,v_1,v_2)) \leq \omega(G) $.